# What is the most efficient way to implement a facebook / twitter style feed in the MEAN stack? Should I consider socket.io?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongoose, socket.io, mean-stack

I was thinking about using angular's $interval to periodically query and check for new post, but then I've also read about socket.io.

This made me curious as to the best way to accomplish this from a cost-effective / scalable / efficient view point.

Can implementing socket.io in your build greatly increase the cost of hosting (on a platform such as heroku)?

Just wondering if someone can help my weigh relevant pros and cons.

Comment: I"m curious about know more about this too. Seems like a relevant question. Confused by the down voting .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

socketio is a good solution for what you want to achieve. I don't know well heroku, but I use it with amazon aws and nodejs and it works fine. you can use interval and the http service of angular, but you will waist a lot of time for the heavy handshake of http protocol. socketio is trying to use websockets first (ws or secure wss) and it is much lighter when considering "network waist". it has a fallback to use the regular http long polling....go for it with socketio. you'll have a little work to do (really easy) to adjust sock.on listeners and emitters inside a service, and bind your view to this service, or use rootscope broadcast instead... enjoy :)